# How to debug npm ERR! errno -4094?

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-router, react-router-dom, npm-install

I'm doing my first React project, and following the MOOC instructions, I've had to create routes by this command : **npm install react-router-dom**

Then the console return me these errors :

[Errors displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0UEk.png)

I tried to :

- do it with my IDE closed,
- the project was not running,
- in different command prompt

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all installed dependencies and then reinstall them again:

##### Clean cache (might help)

`npm cache clean --force`

##### Delete modules of project

`rm -rf node_modules/`

##### Reinstall modules of project

`npm install`